# Error when importing merged osm.pbf files into nominatim's PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, nominatim, osmium

Im using Nominatim 3.3 (https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/tree/master/3.3) within docker. I already imported succesfully 2 regions (not together, my PostgreSQL database contained one region at a time).

I need to import multiple regions, I merged my osm.pbf files from GEOFABRIK (https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/alsace.html and https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/monaco.html).

I have merged the files with the following command:

```
osmium cat alsace-latest.osm.pbf monaco-latest.osm.pbf -o alsace-monaco.osm.pbf
```

The merged file (alsace-monaco.osm.pbf) seems correct (it's size is the sum of my files) but when i'm trying to import it with the [init.sh](https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/blob/master/3.3/init.sh) script I have the following error :

```
Reading in file: /data/alsace-monaco.osm.pbf
Using PBF parser.
Processing: Node(10622k 196.7k/s) Way(1728k 50.82k/s) Relation(33999 3399.90/s)2019-06-18 15:20:25.035 UTC [207] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "planet_osm_rels_pkey"
2019-06-18 15:20:25.035 UTC [207] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(11980) already exists.
2019-06-18 15:20:25.035 UTC [207] CONTEXT:  COPY planet_osm_rels, line 34002
2019-06-18 15:20:25.035 UTC [207] STATEMENT:  COPY planet_osm_rels FROM STDIN
Processing: Node(10622k 196.7k/s) Way(1729k 50.88k/s) Relation(34010 3091.82/s)  parse time: 100s
Node stats: total(10622020), max(6553775687) in 54s
Way stats: total(1729949), max(697847840) in 34s
Relation stats: total(34208), max(9698494) in 12s
COPY_END for planet_osm_rels failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "planet_osm_rels_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(11980) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY planet_osm_rels, line 34002

Error occurred, cleaning up
2019-06-18 15:20:26.034 UTC [94] ERROR:  relation "place" does not exist at character 15
2019-06-18 15:20:26.034 UTC [94] STATEMENT:  select * from place limit 1
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Nominatim\DatabaseError: [500]: Database query failed

  thrown in /app/src/lib/DB.php on line 187
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] LOG:  incomplete message from client
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] CONTEXT:  COPY place, line 707521
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] STATEMENT:  COPY place (osm_type, osm_id, class, type, name, admin_level, address, extratags, geometry) FROM STDIN
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] ERROR:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] CONTEXT:  COPY place, line 707521
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] STATEMENT:  COPY place (osm_type, osm_id, class, type, name, admin_level, address, extratags, geometry) FROM STDIN
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe
2019-06-18 15:20:26.045 UTC [204] STATEMENT:  COPY place (osm_type, osm_id, class, type, name, admin_level, address, extratags, geometry) FROM STDIN
```

I'm new with docker and nominatim, I've already succesfully imported my first file (alsace.osm.pbf) and then I removed the existing postgre base and I sucessfully imported the second one (monaco.osm.pbf). So i don't know why it wouldn't work witht the merged file. I never worked with PostgreSQL.

Comment: the integrity of the files will not be kept when you concatenate them. I suggest to use `osmium merge` instead, and maybe even run `osmium renumber` afterwards (you can try that on the current file, too).

Comment: It worked thanks, but I wanted to do it for bigger files (france and germany ~ 7 GB). The process exit after few seconds , seems the operation is too complex for my computer. Any idea ?

Comment: osmium will attempt to load all data into memory (for `osmium sort` the docs mention the memory footprint being 10 times the size of the compressed pbf files). best bet: increase swap space (or create a swapfile) on your system (linux I guess?). however, a disk based temp memory *significantly* increases processing time...

Comment: @Jules did you just try osmium merge or apply osmium renumber to solve the key violation problem?

Comment: @nassertahani i used osmium merge and it worked